# Graph Creation in r

Tags: r

I am trying to calculate the city wise spend on each product on yearly basis.Also including graphical representation however I am not able to get the graphs on R?

```
Top_11 <- aggregate(Ca_spend["Amount"],
               by = Ca_spend[c("City","Product","Month_Year")], 
               FUN="sum")

A <- ggplot(Top_11,aes(x=City,Month_Year,y=Amount))

A <-geom_bar(stat="identity",position='dodge',fill="firebrick1",colour="black")

A <- A+facet_grid(.~Type)
```

This is the code I am using.I am trying to plot City,Product,Year on same graph.

```
VARIABLES-(City              product   Month_Year   Amount) 
(OBSERVATIONS)- New York     Gold          2004              $50,0000    (Sample  DATA Type)
```

Comment: @Gregor    A <- ggplot(Top_11,aes(x=City,Month_Year,y=Amount))

A <-geom_bar(stat="identity",position='dodge',fill="firebrick1",colour="black")

A <- A+facet_grid(.~Type)

This is the code I am using.I am trying to plot City,Product,Year and Amount on same graph.

VARIABLES-(City product Month_Year Amount) (OBSERVATIONS)- New York Gold 2004 $50,0000 (Sample DATA Type)

Comment: When you say "city, product, year on same graph", how do you imagine that looking? `ggplot` works well when you map one column to aesthetic dimension. Inside `aes()`, you have `x = City` and `y = Amount`, so I see City on the x-axis and Amount on the y-axis. How do you want to represent Product and Year? Colors? Facets? Something else?

Comment: structure(list(City = c("BANGALORE", "BOMBAY", "CALCUTTA", "CHENNAI", 
"COCHIN"), Product = c("Gold", "Gold", "Gold", "Gold", "Gold"
), Month_Year = c(2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004), Amount = c(9289878.54, 
6987853.53, 7477140.98, 1059618.5, 7315850.15)), row.names = c(NA, 
5L), class = "data.frame")  @Gregor Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd try this:

```
ggplot(Top_11,aes(x=City, fill = Product, y=Amount)) +
  geom_col() +
  facet_wrap(~Month_Year)
```

For your 5 rows of sample data, that gives the graph below. You can play around with which variable goes to `fill` (fill color), `x` (x-axis), and `facet_wrap` (for small multiples). I see in your code you tried `facet_grid(.~Type)`, but that won't work unless you have a column named `Type`.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much.This is what I was looking.I am new to R so was facing bit difficulty.Thanks again!